# PowerShell: How can I join the property results of two method members?

Tags: sql, powershell, reporting-services, wmi

If a method has two members who's results are in an array, can they be joined?

In the code below, the method "**GetReportServerUrls**" returns an array of **ApplicationName** and **URLs** each with two elements that correlate (e.g. ReportServerWebService=http://localhost:80/ReportServer). In this case the ApplicationName results are constant but the URL's are not. How can I join the array elements so I can get the URL for ReportServerWebService?

```
$rsCnfg = Get-WmiObject -NameSpace "root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\$rsWmiN\$rsWmiV" -class MSReportServer_Instance -ComputerName localhost
$rsCnfg.GetReportServerUrls()

__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     : 
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        : 
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 4
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         : 
__NAMESPACE      : 
__PATH           : 
ApplicationName  : {ReportServerWebService, ReportServerWebApp}
HRESULT          : 0
Length           : 2
URLs             : {http://localhost:80/ReportServer, http://localhost:80/Reports}
PSComputerName   :
```

**UPDATE:** I know there has to be a better way but this is what I've come up with so far:

```
$rsCnfg = Get-WmiObject -NameSpace "root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\$rsWmiN\$rsWmiV" -class MSReportServer_Instance -ComputerName localhost
$index = [array]::IndexOf($rsCnfg.GetReportServerUrls().ApplicationName,"ReportServerWebService")
$rswsURL = $rsCnfg.GetReportServerUrls().URLs[$Index]


> http://localhost:80/ReportServer
```

Comment: iterate thru the 1st collection of items, grab the same-index item from the 2nd collection, then either build a new property with a string value [perhaps with `-join`], OR build a new property with a PSCustomObject that holds the two properties in one new property.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I stumbled upon your suggestion as a possible solution. As far along as I have come with PowerShell, implementing it has eluded me. Could you possibly provide some sudo code?

Comment: @Abraham-Zinala, I want the URL that corresponds to ReportServerWebService.

Comment: I'm not understanding this. You want `ReportServerWebService` concatenated to `http://localhost:80/ReportServer`?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, Correct. The parameters ApplicationName and URLs will always return 2 values. ApplicationName will ALWAYS return ReportServerWebService and ReportServerWebApp. URLs will always return 2 results each coinciding with the value position of ApplicationName.

Comment: So you want the output to be: `http://localhost:80/ReportServerReportServerWebService`? That's what concatenating is. That's your expected output?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, correct.

Comment: @ToToRoYN - it looks like AbrahamZinala has posted a good example of the idea i was thinking of in the Answer below. great ... and goo luck! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$rsCnfg = Get-WmiObject -NameSpace "root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\$rsWmiN\$rsWmiV" -class MSReportServer_Instance -ComputerName localhost
$rsCnfg.GetReportServerUrls() | Select-Object -Property `
    @{
        N='URL';
        E={
            ($_.URLs -replace '/[^/]*$') + $_.ApplicationName
        }
    }
```